# "Bet on" vs "bet for"

Tags: prepositions

I want to know how to use the verb "bet" for expressing a commitment to, say, a new form of society. The reason why I'd rather use "bet" is because I need to express the sense of risk that would represent such a commitment, and the fact that such a bet can be lost. These are sentences where I would like to express that idea:

> **1.** My bet is for/on a new society.

> **2.** The bet for/on communism is a very risky one.

> **3.** We are placing our bets on democracy rather than on totalitarianism.

For each of these cases (and maybe others), I'd like to know whether I should use "for", "on", or other preposition.

Comment: Why not use “commit”  or “commitment” ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Bet on" and "Bet for" are interchangeable, but when you say "bet on" it has a connotation that makes your bet sound like something of little importance to yourself or whoever's bet it is, but when you say "bet for" it sounds like you are really "for" the success of something, so it would depend on the context of the statement to decide when to use which phrase. Like statement 1, "My bet is for/on a new society". If you said "My bet is on a new society" it sounds like you're saying "I think a new society will work best", but if you say "My bet is for a new society" sounds like "I want a new society", so whichever message you are trying to convey will help you chose whether to use "bet on" or "bet for". I hope this was helpful!

Comment: Could I say, "I am betting for that to happen"?

Comment: Yes, you could, that is also interchangeable with "My bet is for that to happen" or "I bet for that to happen". It just depends on your preference and what sounds best with the text surrounding it.